# tikz externalize works on some figures but not on others

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pgfmath, externalize

Trying to speed up the compilation of a book I'm writing, I learned about the "externalize" feature of tikz.  However, there are some figures it bombs out on with the error

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "pgfbugfig/pgfbug-figure1" "\def\tikzexter
nalrealjob{pgfbug}\input{pgfbug}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'pgfb
ugfig/pgfbug-figure1'
```

This seems to happen when I use the datavisualization format.  I have constructed a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{pgfbugfig/}
\begin{document}

The first figure:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,domain=-2:2]
\draw[very thin, color=gray] (-2,0) grid (2, 4);
\draw (-2.1, 0) -- (2.1, 0);
\draw (0, 0) -- (0, 4.1);
\draw[thick] plot [smooth](\x,{4*exp(-2*\x*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The second figure:
\begin{center}
\tikz\datavisualization
  [scientific axes,
   visualize as line]
data {
  x, y
  0, 0
  1, 1
};
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

If I run this with the `\tikzexternalize` commented out, it works and I get the expected PDF.  With it enabled, it will generate an externalized PDF for the first picture but it will error out on the second.

The actual error in the pgfbugfig/pgfbug-figure1.log file is this:

```
    A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to d
    isable this.
    \openout4 = `pgfbugfig/pgfbug-figure1.dpth'.
    
   ! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
     got an ill-formatted floating point number `'. The unreadable part was near ''
```

Any hints for what could be going on here..?  Is "externalize" incompatible with the datavisualization option?  And if so, can I somehow "exclude" only those figures so I can still enjoy the speedup for the others?

Comment: If I use the `tikzpicture` environment with the second example, it works.

Comment: If I add `\begin{tikzpicture}` between the `\begin{center}` and `\tikz\datavisualization` and `\end{tikzpicture}` before the `\end{center}`, then I get `Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`, due to a `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig `...  (by the way, I _have_ learned about `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable`, although I'd still like to know what's going on...

Comment: Did you remove the `\tikz`?

Comment: No, I didn't - and that caused the TeX capacity exceeded.  Using a `tikzpicture` environment rather than `\tikz` works - I cannot seem to "upvote" an answer in a comment, but for future readers: `\externalize` does not seem to cooperate well with "raw" `\tikz` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug because the `external` library should work with a `\tikz` diagram and it does with the simple example given in the manual.

Unsurprisingly, the Data Visualization module also loads the `fpu` library which might hint at why this diagram fails and not the other.

Consider the work-around to also use the `tikzpicture` environment in this case. This doesn't break the externalization process.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{pgfbugfig/}
\begin{document}

The first figure:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,domain=-2:2]
\draw[very thin, color=gray] (-2,0) grid (2, 4);
\draw (-2.1, 0) -- (2.1, 0);
\draw (0, 0) -- (0, 4.1);
\draw[thick] plot [smooth](\x,{4*exp(-2*\x*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

The second figure:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization
  [scientific axes,
   visualize as line]
data {
  x, y
  0, 0
  1, 1
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote, but this is exactly what solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Sander You can accept the answer, though, by clicking on the greyed out tick at top left of the response you want to accept.